# Registering as sole trader in UK although most of my work is conducted abroad/online

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, italy

I would like some advice.

I am a British national (not resident at present). I offer a range of language related services (translation, interpreting services, teaching, travel agent for language trips to the UK).

For the last 3 years I have paid my taxes in Italy, where I will reside permanently until 31st December 2015. I am registered as freelance here. From Jan 2016, I intend to relocate back to the UK (my family own a property there) but most of my work will still be abroad (I’m usually away for months at a time – a lot of my work is connected to Italy) and online.

I intend to close my Italian VAT, and register as a sole trader in the UK, but my doubts are:

1)  Is there a minimum number of months per year one must spend in the UK to be eligible to register as a sole trader (or to pay tax in the UK in general)?

2)  As a sole trader, do I need an office in the UK or can my family property act as my home address/office?

FYI, I already have a National Insurance Number and have paid tax to the UK government as an employee in the past.

Thank you for your help!

Maria

Comment: `I intend to close my Italian VAT, and register as a sole trader in the UK` Why ? Is it just because you are coming to UK or some other reason ? Where are your payments coming into ? Why a sole trader and not a private limited company ?